# Does Czill reproduction in Midnight at the Well of Souls make sense?

Tags: jack-l-chalker, midnight-at-the-well-of-souls

In Jack Chalker's *Midnight at the Well of Souls* (and sequels), the structure of the Well World allows him to introduce a large number of alien organisms.  One of the most interesting alien races (and one of two Well World aliens featured in *Barlowe's Guide to Extraterrestrials*) are the [Czill](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Czill).

However, since I first read the book, it has always seemed that there was a basic problem with Czill biology.  Chalker repeatedly notes that the Czill reproduce by fission.  A single Czill splits in half vertically, leaving two "offspring."  One of the major characters in the book, Vardia, who has been turned into a Czill, undergoes a split this way.  However, the "offspring" are each considered to be a continuation of the original Czill, although they are generally separated immediately after the split, so that they can develop into different individuals.

That this analysis is correct receives metaphysical confirmation when the prophecy that all the recent "entries" will go together to the heart of the Well World is fulfilled.  Both of the Czills that were originally Vardia are part of the trip into the Well.

However, having this as the only mentioned method of reproduction causes all sorts of problems.  With only binary fission as a mode of reproduction, that means that the Czills must be effectively immortal, since each binary "offspring" is a continuation of the progenitor.  What's more, it means that every Czill living in the story's present must be either an "entry" who arrived at the Well World through a portal and was transformed into a Czill or one of the

> original Markovians whose souls populated the Well World.

Yet both of these possibilities seem to be precluded by other information.  (It is mentioned that "entry" Czills are uncommon in either the first or second book, and

> Nathan Brazil appears to be the last original Markovian in the universe.)

Did I overlook something here, or did Chalker?  Is there another (sexual?) method of Czill reproduction mentioned or implied anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis seems to make sense, but it doesn't matter - biology erases everything in the long run.  Physically, because body function forces a general turnover of matter in the body over time *[fun fact: It is estimated that essentially every atom in a human body gets replaced over a period of about seven years]*; given 'how long' the Czill hex has existed, all of the atoms in the hex have been shuffled around in and out of Czill bodies so many times that the notion of being 'an original Markovian' for them loses any meaning.  Mentally, because of what you yourself mentioned - each Czill gradually develops into a different individual; since brains are finite, all original Markovian memories must have long ago been lost in favor of more recent memories.

NOTE: Nathan Brazil is an exception here because the Well explicitly maintains his Markovian mind in its current state.  We see this in the first book - Nathan is initially oblivious of his past, except for occasional flashes of memory, but just before they all enter the Well he remembers everything.

Comment: There aren't any original Markovian memories. The whole point was to start fresh, so the Markovians who were transformed into whatever new species had their minds wiped only knowing what an individual of that species at whatever point in development they were would know. So even if some of the current Czill are indeed sort of Markovian individuals, they wouldn't know it, and the Well security system wouldn't recognize them as such.