# Sci-fi book featuring an alien character which reproduced by budding

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm looking for a sci-fi book I read in probably the mid to late 80s. I recall an alien character — possibly not immediately identified as an alien — that was "pregnant" with its offspring, which was budding off its back(?).

The alien was friendly, I think, in possibly a political or exploration context, though I can't say if it had actual contact with humans in the novel. The alien character may have been something of an outcast among its own people.

I have some association with this character being near the sea, as for a long time I thought the book was *The Face of the Waters* by Robert Silverberg. However, I've recently re-read *The Face of the Waters*, and it's clearly not the story I was thinking of.

Comment: There are lots of sci-fi aliens that reproduce by budding, e.g. in Van Vogt's "War of Nerves" which became part of *The Voyage of the Space Beagle*, although that's probably not the one you're looking for. Can you recall any more story details? Are the budding aliens friendly or hostile?

Comment: I don't remember much at all, unfortunately. The alien was friendly, I think, in possibly a political or exploration context, though I can't say if it had actual contact with humans in the novel. The alien character may have been something of an outcast from its own people. Sorry, I know that's not much to go on!

Comment: Maybe Jack Chalker's Czill? See [this q&a for details](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/178035/139981)

Comment: Thank you. The story doesn't sound familiar but I'm interested enough to want to read it now!